Stative verbs: Have, having, see, seeing. How do they work?
I have been browsing forums for a long time but haven't received any answer that has satisfied my doubts.
We've learned that stative verbs shouldn't be used with '-ing', except if their meaning is distinct from the original and that this same meaning doesn't have a stative connotation.

Ex: I'm having a coffee = I'm drinking a coffee!

The ISSUE arises when it's said that it's possible to use 'having, seeing, etc.' when it's about an action that occurs only at that moment, with a predetermined beginning, middle, and end.
Some say it's normal to use verbs like this in that last situation. Others say you shouldn't use them because it's a grammatical error. | Which advice should one follow?

These verbs, can be used with the progressive,  but exceptionally. The answer to this question provides a basis in the the explanation of the extent to which the progressive can be used with stative verbs.

Please give examples where "having" meaning to own something, and "seeing" meaning vision, or the ability to see something is used in the progressive tense. This would help visitors and non-native speakers understand your question better.

The most infamous example, years ago, would be the McDonald's ad "I'm loving it". Nowadays nobody blinks twice when someone says they are loving something at that moment e.g. I'm loving her new hair colo(u)r.

Note that future planned events van use the 'am Ving' construction: "We are seeing the bank manager tomorrow."
